# Access permission only to R

Tags: linux, permissions

How I can give access rights only for R (for others)?

For example, when user run `ls` he doesn't see list of files, but can read file, e.g. `cat file26.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By giving others only the execute (x) permission on the containing directory:

```
$ mkdir dir
$ chmod 0711 dir
$ echo yes > dir/file
$ su other_user -c 'ls dir'
Password:
ls: cannot open directory 'dir': Permission denied
$ su other_user -c 'cat dir/file'
Password:
yes
```